# Calculating <input type="date" with jQuery

Tags: jquery, date

I'm struggling with the idea to display the amount of days between the selected date choosen by: `<input type="date" id="date" />` and today.

Based on that I would like to show a specific `<div>`. For example if there are 20 days between the date from the input value and today we show `<div id="20day"></div>` and if there are more then 20 days we show `<div id="21day"></div>`.

Is this possible just with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#date').change(function () {
    var date1 = new Date($(this).val());
    var date2 = new Date();
    var diffDays = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();
    $('body').append('<div id="' + diffDays + '"></div>');
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qMzcR/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm getting very close. The only thing I discovered, the calculation is wrong. If I pick the date from tomorrow and I get 30 days. Thats my code at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/kkcJs/

Comment: I have made some modifications to your code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkcJs/1/) and also if I select 30 Mar, I get **Total 1 days left.**. So, I don't see the 30 days issue.

Comment: Thx and also thx for optimizing my code. About the calculation issue, I think I descripted it wrong. The enduser is supposted to choose a date in the future. So if he picks April 1st, it should show "1 days", and now it shows "30 days". Can you help me with this? THX.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = $('#date').val();
var today = new Date();

var diff = new Date(selected - today);

// get days
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

alert(days);
```

`var days` will contains the number of days. You can go ahead and do whatever you like with the variable. I just used `alert()` here.